# Regex capture multi-line groups

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I'm struggling in creating a regex to capture what's included between two keywords in a multi-line file.

In particular, consider the following file:

```
#%META
# date: 2022-08-27
# generated-by: Me
# id: 1
#%ENDS

#%BODY
....
#%ENDS

#%META
# date: 2022-08-27
# generated-by: Another Me
# id: 2
#%ENDS

#%BODY
....
#%ENDS
```

I wanted to parse what is included between the `#%META` and the `#%ENDS` keywords, if possible, without the leading `#`, i.e., the desired result is to capture both:

```yaml
date: 2022-08-27
generated-by: Me
id: 1
```

and

```yaml
date: 2022-08-27
generated-by: Another Me
id: 2
```

I come out with following regex: `(?<=#%META\n)([\S\s]*?)(?=#%ENDS\n)`.

However this is not capable to identify the two chuncks of text to be matched as well as does not remove the leading `#`.

Could anyone help in that?

Thank's a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pattern to first capture all the parts between `#%META` and `#%ENDS` and then after process the capture group 1 values removing the leading `#` followed by optional spaces.

```
^#%META((?>\R(?!#%(?:META|ENDS)$).*)+)\R#%ENDS$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `#%META` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?>` Atomic group

    - `\R` Match any unicode newline sequence
    - `(?!#%(?:META|ENDS)$)` Negative lookahead, assert that the line is not `#%META` or `#%ENDS`
    - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `)+` Close the atomic group and repeat 1+ times
- `)` Close group 1
- `\R` Match any unicode newline sequence
- `#%ENDS` Match literally
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV98oc/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/5A2Zu)

Example

```
$re = '/^#%META((?>\R(?!#%(?:META|ENDS)$).*)+)\R#%ENDS$/m';
$str = '#%META
# date: 2022-08-27
# generated-by: Me
# id: 1
#%ENDS

#%BODY
....
#%ENDS

#%META
# date: 2022-08-27
# generated-by: Another Me
# id: 2
#%ENDS

#%BODY
....
#%ENDS';

if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    $result = array_map(function ($s) {
        return preg_replace("/^#\h*/m", "", trim($s));
    }, $matches[1]);
    var_export($result);
}
```

Output

```
array (
  0 => 'date: 2022-08-27
generated-by: Me
id: 1',
  1 => 'date: 2022-08-27
generated-by: Another Me
id: 2',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add /m modifier to regex to find all matches
Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/# (.+)\S/m',
    static function ($m) {
        return $m[1];
    },
    $str,
); // or just str_replace('# ', '', $str)
preg_match('/((?<=#%META\n)([\S\s]*?)(?=#%ENDS\n))/m' ,$str, $m);
var_dump($m);
```